# Why is jQuery select event listener triggering multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, dom

Please run [this sample](https://jsfiddle.net/qato40m6/2/) in Google Chrome browser.

#### Stack Snippet

```js
$(function() {
  $(":input").select(function() {
    $("div").text("Something was selected").show().fadeOut(1000);
    alert("Selected");
  });
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(":input").select();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click To Select</button>
<input type="text" value="Some text">
<div></div>
```

Here why jQuery select event listener is triggering multiple times? Does anyone know the reason behind this? And is there any workaround solution for this without using timeout?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3qkvr5zq/2/ - Once it is triggered internally by the `select()` call, but after the `click` handler is exited it is called twice which I assume is done by the render operation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `$(":input")` selector is selecting the button too, so it causes recursion. Either use just `$("input")`, or `$(":input:not(button)")`.

I noticed when the three events are fired, the first doesn't have `originalEvent` property, so we definitely can dismiss it, and the second two has very similar (however not identical) timestamp. You can store the last timestamp in some variable and in event listener compare it with the event's timestamp. If the rounded values of these two are the same, you can dismiss this event.

```
$(function() {
  var lastTimeStamp;
  $("input").select(function(event) {
    if (!event.originalEvent ||
        lastTimeStamp === Math.round(event.timeStamp)) return;
    lastTimeStamp = Math.round(event.timeStamp);
    $("div").text("Something was selected").show().fadeOut(1000);
    alert("Selected");
  });
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("input").select();
  });
});
```

See [updated JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gothdo/qato40m6/20/).

Answer (score 10):

It appears the issue is a combination of:

- the `:input` selector gets the `input` and the `button`, hence multiple events triggered.
- even when using just `input` as the selector there is some odd event propagation being triggered on related elements which is raising the `select` event handler multiple times.

To avoid both of the above, use `input` as the selector and also use `preventDefault()` in the event handler. `stopPropagation()` may also be required, depending on your HTML stucture.

```
$(function() {
    $('input').select(function(e) {
        // e.stopPropagation(); // optional
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#message').text("Something was selected").show().fadeOut(1000);
        console.log('Selected');
    });

    $('button').click(function() {
        $('input').select();
    });
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/qato40m6/6/)

Comment: The wrong selector is indeed the base of the problem, the other problem only persists in Chrome and not in FF & IE.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `e.preventDefault()` will prevent from selecting the text.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: We were all fooled. The select() function needs a prevent default.

Rory McCrossan figured it out. Well done mate.

Incidentally, I'm not sure what the benefit of select() actually is! Something like focus() or on('focus',) might make more sense.  Not Sure what the context is however. The below still follows:

Why waste time using generalised tag/type selectors which may change?  Use an ID, and pick out only the one you want.

If you want to detect multiple, use a class.  If you want to use multiple, but figure out which one you clicked, use a class and an ID. Bind with the class, and identify using `$this.attr('id')`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click To Select</button>
<input type="text" value="Some text" id="pick-me">
<div></div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#pick-me").select(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("div").text("Something was selected").show().fadeOut(1000);
    alert("Selected");
  });
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#pick-me").select();
  });
});
```

Comment: Still fires three times for me on the latest Chrome, see [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gothdo/9ocnq2kd/).

Comment: @Gothdo haha you're right. Bizarre. Going to fix this now!

Comment: Yep, it was the event requireing a preventDefault.  I'm not even sure I ever use the 'select()' method on an input anyway. I always use focus or something similar.

Comment: @TimOgilvy If we use `event.preventDefault();`, it will not allow to select the text through button click.

Comment: `$e.focus()` places focus on the $e element. `$e.select()` places focus on the $e element and selects all the content.